# Add items to select list on the client side in MVC 5 ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to learn more about MVC 5 so I'm writing a bloging site for myself to learn more as I go.

I have set up a select list for tags and would like to be able to add new tags from the create blog entry page rather than having to remember to set the tags up before creating a new post. I'm thinking down the lines of a "Add Tag" button which displays a bootstrap modal window where the user can add a new  tag.

Here is my controller action:

```
public ViewResult CreateBlogPost()
{
    CreateEditBlogViewModel viewModel = new CreateEditBlogViewModel();
    viewModel.BlogPost = new Core.BlogPost();

    viewModel.BlogPost.ShortBody = "<p>Something short and sweet to describe the post</p>";
    viewModel.BlogPost.Body = "<p>Enter something blog worthy here...</p>";

    viewModel.Tags = new SelectList(_blogRepo.BlogTags(), "Id", "Name");
    viewModel.Categories = new SelectList(_blogRepo.BlogCategories(), "Id", "Name");

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And here is the HTML in the view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BlogPost.Tags, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, Model.Tags, new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @data_placeholder = "Start typing to see a list of tags" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tagModal">
            Add Tag
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is my partial view for the modal window:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveTag", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tag-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="tagModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tagModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="tagModalLabel">Enter a name for a new tag</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Enter a new tag name" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Is it possible to add a tag on the client side, persist it into the db and then add it to my tags select list without refreshing the page?

PS: FYI I'm using the Chosen multi-select from [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".chosen-select").chosen()
    </script>
}
```

**EDIT**: I have updated the question with all the code that makes the view give the user the modal window to enter a new tag name. I'm just not sure how to post without navigating away from the page so I'm guessing some sort of Ajax post is required. And then what to do with the data that is returned from that post. How do I then add that new persisted record to the select list?

I know the tag isn't passing to the controller method as it's not bound to any sort of model but being as I'm using a view model on the parent view, I'm not sure how I would handle that here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to dynamically add a new `BlogTag` in the view you will need to post the new tag `Name` using ajax, to a controller method that saves the `BlogTag` and returns its new `ID` value. Your controller method would be something like

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateTag(string name)
{
  BlogTag tag = new BlogTag(){ Name = name };
  db.BlogTags.Add(tag);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return Json(tag.ID);
  // If the above code could result in an error/exception, catch it and return
  // return Json(null);
}
```

Then in the view, handle the dialogs submit button to post the value and update the tag list

```
var url = '@Url.Action("CreateTag")';
var tagList = $('#SelectedTags');
$('#tag-form').submit(function() {
  var tagName = $('#Name').val();
  $.post(url, { name: tagName }, function(id) {
    if (id) {
      // add the new tag to the list box
      tagList.append($('<option></option>').val(id).text($('#Name').val()));
      // trigger the chosen update
      tagList.trigger("chosen:updated");  
    } else {
      // Oops - display an error message?
    }
  }).fail(function (result) {
    // Oops - display an error message?
  });
  return false; // cancel the default submit
});
```

Side note: I would recommend that you create a view model for `BlogTagVM` (containing a property for the `Name` with validation attributes) and an associated partial view (say `_AddBlogTag.cshtml`) that generates the dialog html, so that in the main view you can use `@Html.Partial("_AddBlogTag", new BlogTagVM())` which will allow you to use the strongly typed html helpers, and to include client side validation.

Note also that nested `<form>` elements are invalid html so ensure that html for the dialog is outside the main `<form>` tag for the view.

Comment: I can see how that works and implemented it. I can see the new option get added to the option list in the html source using Firefox developer tools (It would appear I was closer to a solution than I first thought). However, the chosen-select ui element doesn't seem to recognise it until a page refresh. So to clarify - it appends the html source `<option>` list but does not show in the `chosen-select.`

Comment: Cancel that, I read the chosen website and there is a change/update event you can trigger which is `$("#SelectedTags").trigger("chosen:updated");` after `tagList.append($('<option></option>').val(ID).text(tagName.val()));` If you could elaborate on how I would handle a failure to persist the tag in the db I'd gladly +1 also! Cheers.

Comment: I already had the line `tagList.trigger("chosen:updated");` in my answer :). There are a few ways to handle failure - you could `return Json(null)` and in the script check `if (id) { // add option } else { // oops }` or you could return a `HttpStatusCodeResult` indicating an error and then add `.fail(function (result) { // oops });` to the `$.post` function - I have updated the answer with an example

Comment: Excellent thank you. Oops, so you did sorry. I read the dotnetfiddle mostly though and it wasn't in there. Working perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar, I think it might help.  In my case, I'm "moving" values from one list to another (from "available" to "used") and then saving the values of the "used" list.  Anyway, in the controller, the "used" list shows up as an array of strings.  Here's my code:

```
       public ActionResult PinchHit(FormCollection form, LineupViewModel lvm, String[] UsedPlayers)
        {
[Snip]
            if (ModelState.IsValid && lineupResults.IsValid)
            {
[Snip]
                foreach (String usedID in UsedPlayers)
                {
                   gameState.HomeUsedPlayersIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(usedID));
                }
                uow.Repository<GameState>().Update(gameState);
                uow.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "GameSummary");
            }
[Snip]
            return View(lvm2);
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Per my comment:

Here is an AJAX call-back mechanism I used to retrieve data from the database without reloading the page, you could use it to save data to the database instead.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPositions(id, control) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetPositions", "Lineup")",
                data:
                {
                    id: id
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(control).html("");
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $(control).append("<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>");
                    }
                    );
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

then in the controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetPositions(int id)
    {
        Player player = uow.Repository<Player>().GetById(id);
        if (player == null)
        {
            return (null);
        }
        List<SelectListItem> positionList = new SelectList(player.Positions, "ID", "ShortName").ToList();
        return Json(positionList);
    }
```

Pretty standard stuff really.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this would result in a page load, correct? I'm trying to avoid that if possible. I know I could post a form, and reload the view with the pre entered fields and update the select list but I'm hoping to do it client side.

Comment: What I'm doing is gathering all the values client-side and then persisting them during post (when the user is done with all the changes and clicks the submit button.)  You're asking that the changes be persisted each time they add a tag without reloading the page?  In that case you'll need to have an AJAX callback to a JSON method.  I'll Edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks but as a complete beginner especially with JS it's not quite enough information to get me to where I need to be I think. I've got a modal window with a form that opens but my form data doesn't pass across to my controller and I'm not sure how to handle the new tag once it's persisted. (I thought I was closer previously than I actually am!)